# How to create a savings bank system where program stops looping after balance doubles

Tags: java

I am a tasked to create a program that runs as described, programmed in **Java**:

> Illustrate the growth of money in a savings account. The user enters the initial amount (as a decimal) and the interest rate which are used to calculate the number of years until the money doubles and the number of years until the money reaches a million dollars. (you will need to use more than 1 loop).
>
> Note: The balance at the end of each year is
>
> (1  + r) * balance
>
> where balance is the previous balance, and r is the annual rate of interest in decimal form.

However, I cannot find the error in my code. What happens is that it continuously writes "Your balance will double in " and then the number infinitely grows.

Here is the code:

> Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
> double years = 0;
> double futureVaule;

```
    System.out.print("Please enter the amount of money you would like to deposit, as a decimal:\n>>");
    double balance = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.print("Please enter the interest rate of your deposit, as a percent:\n>>");
    double r = input.nextDouble();
    
    do
    {
        futureValue = (1 + r) * balance;
        years = years + 1;
        System.out.println("Your balance will double in " 
                + Math.round(years) + " year(s).");
        
        
    }while(futureValue <= balance*2);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes then post the same.

Comment: Never mind, the problem's been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
futureValue = balance;
double doubleBalance = balance*2;

  while(futureValue <= doubleBalance)
     {
           futureValue += futureValue * (( 1 + r)/100);
           years++;
     }

  System.out.println("Your balance will double in " 
                        + years + " year(s).");
```

Comment: No Problem, glad to help. I see your new to Stack Overflow, so if you click the arrow next to my answer it will mark it as solved.